# How to write a C++ API class that will allow a user to register its own callback functions?

Tags: c++11, callback

Let's say a user links his app against a library I wrote and I want to let him specify a callback function that I will call whenever an error occurs in my library. The implementation below works but I want to double check that I'm not missing something here:

- Thread safety
- DLL initialization issues
- Public API considerations (I'm giving away a reference to an instance from the DLL is that OK?)
- Anything that could be done better to hide implementation details from the public API?

**errordispatcher.h**:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

namespace WE
{
class ErrorDispatcher 
    {
    public:
    
        ErrorDispatcher()
        {}

        explicit ErrorDispatcher(std::function<void(std::string)> user_func)
        : error_callback_func{user_func}
        {}
        
        virtual ~ErrorDispatcher(){}
        
        static ErrorDispatcher& getInstance()
        {
            return instance_;
        }
        
        void setErrorCallback(std::function<void(std::string)> user_func)
        {
            error_callback_func = nullptr;
            if (user_func)
                error_callback_func = user_func;
        }
        
        void dispatchError(std::string message)
        {
            if (error_callback_func)
                error_callback_func(message);
        }
        
    private:
    
        explicit ErrorDispatcher(const ErrorDispatcher&) = delete;
        explicit ErrorDispatcher(ErrorDispatcher&&) = delete;
        ErrorDispatcher& operator = (const ErrorDispatcher&) = delete;
        ErrorDispatcher& operator = (ErrorDispatcher&&) = delete;

        static ErrorDispatcher instance_;
        std::function<void(std::string)> error_callback_func = nullptr;
    };
}
```

*NOTE: above I have inline implementation details in the public header to make this post shorter but they will be moved to a .cpp and won't be part of the public header*

**errordispatcher.cpp**:

```cpp
#include "errordispatcher.h"

namespace WE
{
    ErrorDispatcher ErrorDispatcher::instance_;
}
```

**apitest.h**

```cpp
namespace WE
{
    void dllFunctionThatMightGiveError();
}
```

**apitest.cpp**

```cpp
#include "errordispatcher.h"
#include "apitest.h"

namespace WE
{
    void dllFunctionThatMightGiveError()
    {
        // Some error happens in dll so call user function and give a message to the user!
        ErrorDispatcher::getInstance().dispatchError("Error in DLL!");
    }
}
```

**main.cpp** (***USER APP***)

```cpp
#include "errordispatcher.h"
#include "apitest.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void error_callback(std::string message)
{
    std::cout << message << "\n";
}

int main(void)
{
    WE::ErrorDispatcher::getInstance().setErrorCallback(error_callback);
    WE::ErrorDispatcher::getInstance().dispatchError("Error in APP!");
    WE::dllFunctionThatMightGiveError();
    return 0;
}
```

**Output is**:

> Error in APP!
>
> Error in DLL!

Comment: Templated classes should never be part of public Dll interface - don't ignore compiler warnings. Replace `error_callback(std::string)` with `error_callback(const char*)`

Comment: It is not thread safe, it will only reliably work if your DLL and Client are compiled using basically identical compilers and standard libraries and interfaces (no version safety), common errors in the implementation of `std::function` (the empty `std::function` sometimes doesn't evaluate as `false` in my experience) are issues.  I see no problems with regards to DLL initialization, however.  I disagree about replacing `std::string` with `const char*` bit from @alexfarber: given every other dependency you have, that is the least of your worries (`std::function` is a far bigger issue).

Comment: Generally, you need to define callback type and its parameters in plain C, without any std tricks.

Comment: @AlexFarber: The library will be written entirely in C++11 and it will have restrictions on which compiler the user can use, I will provide the user with binaries for multiple compilers ex. MinGW-w64 (sjlj/dwarf) g++ 4.8.1 and above, native linux g++ 4.8.1 and above or VS 2013 Nov. CTP and above. Maybe I will make it open source someday and let the user chose the compiler to build the lib.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Would have been great if I knew code review existed.